# Is there a way to check expanded/collapsed state of a React-popper

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, popper.js, react-popper

I want to be able to know if the `react-popper` is open or closed at any given point in time. I can't seem to find any references to this usecase in the documentation. Is this unavailable? Should I simply set up a local state to keep track of this?